# Use an Email Template from a CakePHP Plugin

Tags: email, cakephp, plugins

I have a CakePHP Shell Script that's sending an email. This script is contained in a CakePHP plugin (foo).

Setting the Email Template as

```
$this->Email->template = "foo/email_template_name";
```

Does not work, the email sends successfully, however the email just says

```
Not Found: /path_to_app/app/views/elements/email/html/foo/email_template_name.ctp
```

I have verified that the template is named correctly and does exist.

Minor Notes:

```
$this->Email->sendAs = "both";
```

If the template is moved to `/path_to_app/app/views/elements/email/html/foo/email_template_name.ctp`
it does work correctly. However I was hoping to ship this as much as possible as a self contained email including the templates in the plugin itself.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell CakeEmail the name of the Plugin. (Cake 2.0.x)

In your Model

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->template('Foo.email_template_name');
```

or Controller

```
$this->email->template('Foo.email_template_name');
```

You need to create the views for the email:

```
Plugin/Foo/View/Emails/html/email_template_name.ctp
Plugin/Foo/View/Emails/text/email_template_name.ctp
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Cake was telling me my file was missing when it was not.  The solution was to prefix the name of my template with the plugin name.

Answer (score 1):

Please post all your code for $this->Email.

Check:

```
$this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
```

Have you tried

```
$this->Email->template = "email_template_name";
```

and moving the template to

```
/path_to_app/app/views/elements/email/html/email_template_name.ctp
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike, yep all have been verified.

Answer (score 1):

Check your path again!

I've faced the same problem and I realized that I had placed my template at:
`/path_to_app/app/plugins/my_plugin_name/views/elements/email/my_template.ctp`

But the correct path is:
`/path_to_app/app/plugins/my_plugin_name/views/elements/email/html/my_template.ctp`

Since I'm using 'html' value as "sendAs" on my Controller

`$this->Email->sendAs = 'html';`

Comment: Which version of cakephp are you using ?

Comment: I guess it was on 1.3.8. What trouble are you dealing with? I'm working now at 2.0, but not started to send e-mail yet :)

Comment: this worked with the path as suggested by colares in cakephp 1.3.11

Answer (score 1):

Simply this feature is not implemented in cakephp 1.3. 
You will get it in the fresh cakephp 2.0.0 release 
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lorenzo/2011/10/16/cakephp_2_0_released

since the bug has been fixed:
http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1743-cakeemail-in-plugins-doesnt-work-well-with-views

You may eventually ask or provide a backport in 1.3. I don't know cakephp backfixing strategy and allowances.